# How to remove enter key at the end of SQL data and export it to Excel using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to export SQL data to EXCEL but there are some enter key at the end of some data, so when it written to excel data that sits right to the enter key data will be written to the next row where it is suppose to place beside

I was trying to use substr() but not really sure how to use it, because I am new to PHP

```html
<?php
function leadZero($element)
{
  return substr(trim($element),0,1) === "0" ? "'".$element : $element;
}
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

$user_query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
//echo $user_query;
// Write data to file
$flag = false;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_query)) {
    if (!$flag) {
        // display field/column names as first row
        echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
        $flag = true;
    }
    echo implode("\t", array_map('leadZero', $row))."\r\n";

}
?>
```

Comment: I *highly* suggest looking into [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) and CSV related functions for what you're attempting to accomplish. They're going to do a lot of the parsing, and output formatting for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**try this for delete new line chars:**

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $string));
```